# Call a non-static variable so it can be used by another class (cannot instantiate)

Tags: java, object, non-static

I have a problem

I have some classes of objects, they are called "cat" "dog" etc..

Within these classes I have assigned each cat and dog object their own integer energy level      (so when they "move" through a 2dimensional array they loose and gain energy). 
I reference it by saying this.energylevel.

Because "energylevel" it is specific to each object I cannot make it static.
how can I let the "dog class" see the energy level of the cat objects that is stored non statically within the "cat class"?

and I cannot instantiate `Cat c = new Cat();` within the dog class it is already done within the main method.

This is all part of a massive project so forgive me if I have not explained it clearly enough

Comment: How do you want the `Dog` to get the `Cat`?

Comment: You can create a helper that passes data between different object in your main class.  That way you can tell `dogA` what `catA` is doing or you could tell `dogA` what `dogB` is doing.  You would simply need a method with two parameters, one for the object to tell, the other for the object to tell the first about.  You can then add a method to the `Dog` and `Cat` classes that accepts this information and reacts to it.

Comment: The solution is in every book that teaches you the basics of object-oriented programming or Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a static method inside the Cat object that will return the non-static variable based on the Cat's ID. You'll need to keep a list of Cats in a static map inside the Cat object.

```
private static HashMap<String,Cat> cats = new HashMap<String,Cat>();
...
public static int getEnergy(String catId) {
    Cat myCat = cats.get(catId);
    return myCat.getEnergy();
}

public int getEnergy() {
    return this.energy()
}
```

Alternatively as requested, if you want to search by X,Y:

```
private static ArrayList<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();

private int energy = 100;
private int x = 0;
private int y = 0;
...
public static int getEnergy(int x, int y) {
    //Energy of -1 being the error (not found) state.
    int energy = -1;
    for(Cat cat : cats) {
        if(cat.getX() == x && cat.getY() == y) {
            energy = cat.getEnergy();
        }
    }
    return energy;
}

public int getEnergy() {
    return this.energy()
}

public int getX() {
    return this.x;
}

public int getY() {
    return this.y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks GavinCattell, great answer but is there a way to make the Cat's ID to be equal to a location in a 2d array?

Comment: Can two Objects appear on the same location?

Comment: Hey thanks again but i wrote out the code and i get an error at "return myCat.getEnergy();" it still says non static  method getEnergy() cannot be accessed from a static context, and the "public static int getEnergy(int x, int y)" is missing a return statement

Comment: A few typos in there, I've cleaned them up. Please have another look.

Comment: Sorry man I output the energy levels and it says they are all -1 for the cats, i checked and triple checked to make sure i did nothing wrong

Comment: The above answer definitely would not work by itself. It would all depend on the objects setting their correct X,Y, and the objects being added to the static ArrayList. If you want more information you'll have to post more of your code, including how you're setting the locations and energy, etc.